# Begin sessions using different QuickBooks versions programmatically

Tags: quickbooks

I'm accessing a QuickBooks file from code using this call

```
win32com.client.Dispatch("QBXMLRP2.RequestProcessor")
```

I plan to install more than one version of QuickBooks on my computer. Is there a way to specify which version of QuickBooks is being used to open the session? I want to address particular versions of QuickBooks so that my program is in compliance with the restriction that only one QB file can be opened at a time by an SDK application. (For example, I might begin a session with company1.qbw with QuickBooks Pro, and another session with company2.qbw with QuickBooks Premier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one QuickBooks file can be opened by the SDK on one machine at one time. Installing multiple versions of QuickBooks doesn't change this. If you have a file open in QuickBooks Pro and you want to open an Enterprise file, you must first close Pro. The only way to open multiple QuickBooks files at the same time with the SDK is to use multiple computers.

Side note: multiple versions of QuickBooks can be run on the same machine and the SDK will work; but don't try installing the Canadian or UK versions, or Reckon (Australia and Singapore) on a machine with the US version installed: that will screw up the SDK.